# How to reconnect a websocket connection after manual close - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here's my methods to open/close socket connection:

```
methods: {
  connect () {
    this.$socket.onopen = () => {
      this.status = 'connected'
      this.$socket.onmessage = ({data}) => {
        this.$socket.send(this.message)
        console.log({ event: "Recieved message", data })
      }
    }
    this.$socket.onclose = (e) => {
      console.log('Socket is closed. Reconnect will be attempted in 1 second.')
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.connect()
      }, 1000)
    }
  },
  disconnect () {
    this.$socket.close()
    this.status = 'disconnected'
  }
}
```

I'm not using socket.io etc, just built in `Websocket` object.
When i manually call `disconnect ()` method - it closes the connection as expected, but when i send message again - it says that connection is closed. Since i call `connect ()` in a mounted, then it won't reconnect if i don't refresh the page.

I've tried using watcher:

```
watch: {
  '$socket': 'connect'
}
```

But no effect. Is there a way to watch for websocket connection status? If it's closed - call `connect ()`, if it's error'ed - call `connect ()` to reconnect it.

Comment: The built-in WebSocket object uses ready states, just like the other HTML APIs. You can listen for readystate 3 - closed. Then create a new connection.

Comment: You mean in a watcher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `connect()` method does nothing to "reconnect" to the WebSocket server. So calling `this.connect()` simply rewrites your `onopen` handler.

You have to take the steps necessary to reconnect to the WebSocket server. The most excellent answer to this question does a great job of explaining a great structure for your code:

[vue: emitting global events from websocket listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677360/vue-emitting-global-events-from-websocket-listener)

Unfortunately, it doesn't answer your specific question. So I've forked the sandbox from that answer and added the modified code below that allows you to achieve your goal.

```
import Vue from "vue";

const url = "wss://echo.websocket.org";
let socket;

const emitter = new Vue({
  methods: {
    send(message) {
      if (1 === socket.readyState) socket.send(message);
    },
    close() {
      if (1 === socket.readyState) {
        emitter.$emit("message", "Closing Socket.");
        socket.close();
        socket = null; // prevent memory leak
      }
    },
    connect() {
      socket = new WebSocket(url);
      socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
        emitter.$emit("message", msg.data);
      };
      socket.onerror = function(err) {
        emitter.$emit("error", err);
      };
      emitter.$emit("message", "Openning Socket.");
    }
  }
});

emitter.connect();

export default emitter;
```

To see how this service is used, check out `index.js` in the running sample is here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ry4993q654

Comment: Thanks, i've noticed that my `connect()` was useless, because i didn't used `new Websocket()` instance to open it. Your answer suggests to create a new file, e.g. socket.js and importing it in my component? like `import emitter from './socket'` Also what if i want to open connection only if user is logged in?

Comment: ref the new file question, look at the structure of the solution in the codesanbox. That should answer that question (`import Socket from './socket'`). Ref logged in user:  call `Socket.connect()` in your log-in success handers.

Comment: btw, what you have done, is called event bus (publish/subscribe pattern)?

Comment: And it is a common pattern in modern asynchronous environments - like a browser.

Comment: Can i ask you one more question about the last line in `connect()` method: `emitter.$emit("message", "Openning Socket.");` - what purpose it serves? Also you've used same event name `message` multiple times, if i place a listener to `message` event, then it would listen all these events?

Comment: Don't mind the Qs at all. Last line in connect serves no purpose other than logging and can be removed if not needed.  RE: `message`: Yes, you can listen for the event name "message" and can handle all events emitted with that name.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the close status code before reconnecting.
e.code === 1e3 || e.code === 1001 || e.code === 1005